# Failover DHCP Windows 2012

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp-server

Is Windows 2012 failover DHCP (hot standby) compatible with Windows 2003?

I'm not sure if it's enough to create a Windows 2012 DHCP server and configure failover options.

Comment: What do you mean is it compatible? Do you mean is it compatible with DHCP running on Windows Server 2003?

Comment: There is a server running with windows server 2003 and I want to create a failover dhcp with windows server 2012, I'm not sure if the partner server must be the same version. In 2003 there wasn't dhcp failover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this will not work. Both DHCP Servers must be at least Windows Server 2012.

As an aside, you should be removing 2003 from your environment quickly, not tying it in to new infrastructure. It goes end of extended support early next year.